# What is needed to use ads_read permission in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have a Facebook App that uses only one permission: `ads_read`. What is the simplest way to make it work when it comes to authorization? I see that there's an option to authorize particular ads accounts to the app, but is there any easier way for read-only access? I will have multiple ad accounts there and I am the admin of all those. I would like to be able to use them all without authorizing them separately from the Facebook GUI.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have "Development" access to the Ads API, if so, you need to do this manually at the Facebook App settings (Advanced option). The limitation for this is that you will be able to add your App only to other Apps that you admin.

If you want to allow other Apps you don't manage to use your App, you need a higher level of access.

You can see more info about access level here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

You can request a higher access level using this link:
https://www.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi

I hope it helps.